# esxi passthrough storage adapter

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I run ESXi 5.1.0 (HP version) on HP ProLiant ML310e G8 v2.
There are 2 Storage Adapters:

- Smart Array P222
- Dynamic Smart Array B120i

Storage Adapters are visible in ESXi/Storage Adapters.
[Storage Adadpters](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ot8hpxuxe53qxjh/exsi_sa.png?dl=0)

I need to use passthrough for B120i. In DirectPath I/O Configuration, all devices except B120i are included.
[DirectPath I/O](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h9rgnrrg06z73mb/esxi_dpio.png?dl=0)

**ADD:** This idea to pass through was because of a lack of connectors for an additional SATA HDD cage. However, B120i has poor support for ESXi and raid configuration. Because of that, I've decided to use the free external mini-SAS port. This port goes from the external port back to the server case to connect the SATA backplane.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do it ;)

PCIe passthrough for storage adapters in ESXi isn't guaranteed to work, and is [often a bad choice](https://serverfault.com/questions/488156/esxi-pci-passthrough-smartarray-p812-with-12tb-msa60/488165#488165). I can only think of a small number of situations where it's beneficial (*tape drives or something like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/398515/hosting-a-zfs-server-as-a-virtual-guest/398579#398579)*). But if the B120i device isn't visible in the dialog, then you don't even have the option to use it. It's probably not compatible.

Can you give a better description of why you need to use passthrough of a RAID controller to a virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Smart Array B120i performs very poorly on any raid.
The same disk array performs more satisfactorily at Smart Array P222. For that reason, I bought an External SAS cable to connect to the internal SATA array.

[External SAS cable](https://amzn.to/2l2Qtdm)

Now I am using internal and external SAS connector. The performance of P222 is very good at configuration 4x SAS at raid5 and 4x SATA at raid5.